# How to receive data from Bluetooth OBD-II?

Tags: bluetooth

I am going to order ELM327 Bluetooth on-board diagnostics (OBD) II.

Does Android support Bluetooth OBD-II? Is there any way to pair and receive the data directly on Android?

Comment: More information can also be found at this related question on Mechanics.SE, [OBD2 to Bluetooth adaptor for 2001 Renault](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/546/99)

Answer (score 4):

Torque ([lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.prowl.torquefree), [pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.prowl.torque)) works with most of the ELM327 Bluetooth OBD-II devices.

Be careful though, some of the "cheap" ones don't work well with Ford vehicles.